# Hibernate save as superclass

Tags: hibernate, inheritance

I have an @Entity "Foo" which corresponds to a table in my database "FooTable".
I have created a subclass of Foo, named "Bar" with additional attributes.
Bar does not correspond to a table in my database.
When I save Bar (or any subclass of Foo) I would like it to be simply treated as an instance of "Foo".  I.e. Saved in FooTable.

I've tried using the following annotation on Foo:

```
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
```

..while marking the additional attributes in Bar as @Transient.

However, hibernate now appears to expect a @DiscriminatorColumn.  Without it, it produces the following statement:

```
insert into FooTable (dtype, id) values ('Bar', ?)
```

Resulting in:

```
ORA-00904: "DTYPE": invalid identifier
```

Is there anyway of getting hibernate to persist subclasses of Foo as they would Foo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad.  After posting the question I realized that the simple answer was to use the [entityName](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#save(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) parameter on the Hibernate Session:

Unfortunately for me this isn't an option as I'm accessing my data model through a [Spring repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html).

Editing my initial question to include this additional condition would ruin it.  So I'll leave this as the answer and reexamine the issue from a Spring perspective.